Set Item Metadata on`mintType = Public`
I just created a collection with mintType = Public. So, anyone can mint in that collection. The question is, how do you set default item metadata? So, when anyone mints it, the item will automatically have some set of metadata.
Because I can't use mint and set_metadata at the same time, I don't want to use "Roles" stuff.

From my understanding, this can be handle from the client side. After minting a new collection, you will use the sudo key to submit another extrinsic to set_metadata(). I am not sure what do you mean you can't use mint and set_metadata at the same time. Would be best if you can explain more.
If this is expected to be handled on the Runtime side, I think you can create a wrapper pallet on top of the pallet NFT and use the batch_all() method from pallet_utility to submit the two extrinsics above.
Reference: https://docs.rs/pallet-utility/35.0.0/pallet_utility/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.batch_all
